# Disk Cost does not change for a per machine and a per user install

Tags: wix, windows-installer, wix3.5, diskspace

I want to know how can i change or rather the computer changes the disk cost in case of a per user or a per machine install.

I have an installer that is approximate 50 MB in size when i check in the program files how ever when i am using the DiskCostDlg it shows me 96 MB , i am doing a per user and a per machine install and i am surprised to see that in both the cases the disk requirement is same.

I need to know if there is a possibility of changing the disk requirements or is it a default property of the Wix Installer.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Windows Installer needs extra space for the installation process. This is why it shows more than your total files size. Here is an article with more details:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/heaths/archive/2008/07/24/why-windows-installer-may-require-so-much-disk-space.aspx

> i am doing a per user and a per machine install and i am surprised to
>   see that in both the cases the disk requirement is same.

Per-user or per-machine refers to the install location, they have nothing to do with file size. The installed files are the same and they have the same size for any location.

> I need to know if there is a possibility of changing the disk
>   requirements

It cannot be changed because it's calculated automatically by Windows Installer.